# How to calculate the total logged hours per person per week per month?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have a table which calculates the total logged hours per week per person.

The Excel file has the following structure:

- table where the desired values are calculated
- table with days of the month divided by weeks
- table with the data necessary for the calculations (which is in another sheet)

[Calculation sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7kDV.png) This is where the results will appear.

I have used the following formula:

**=SUMIFS(time,date,">="&A1,date,"<"&A1+7,project,"A")**

This formula calculates the Total Logged Hours by using the weeks of January (from the calendar from the attached picture) based on 3 columns from the data source, namely Logged Hours, Date and Resource (Name_Surname, for identification)

This formula was applied for weeks of January and it gave me the totals per week, displayed in 5 columns for every week of the month.

What I want exactly is that, whenever I change the data source with data for February, March, etc... I would like the calculations (Total Logged Hours, as you can see in the picture) to be made automatically, without intervention on the formula.

How could I do that?

Comment: Your questions should be clear disattaching from what you think it will be, or how it can be. Make sure to make a simplified question reasonable and useful for the whole community like "how calculate time in excell" with steps you make and including photos for clearance

Comment: What you mean by changing the formulas with a button click?

Comment: Hi there. I have updated the question. Hope it's more suitable now. Thank you.

Comment: How is your data set up? Are all the employees/dates for the year in one table? Or is there a table for each employee for each month? You providing that framework will help us with responses. With that said, I don't see much  of a need to change your formula itself, looks like you need to change the values in A1 when you want a different month.

Comment: Hello gns100. I have updated the question.
There are only 3 tables: the results table (where the calculations are displayed), the calendar table and the data source (another sheet where data for January, with those 3 columns, are displayed). I don't want to create additional sheets and tables, I just want to copy/paste in the data source sheet the data for other months and for the formula to just calculate automatically what I need.

Comment: I give yup on this question, you cannot literally be asking, such things as "I want automatically without intervention of the formula" because you're mixing things here, besides your design isn't clear. What does mean automatically for you what!??? You want a Nissan to cross the Avenue automatically without the intervention of the road. Nice question!

Comment: Maybe you want someone to solve this problem automatically for you but Stackoverflow isn't a website for that! Here no one does projects for people. You should be able to identify the problem X then I want X to turn into Y. How X turn into Y. But if you don't have clear what you want, because you're not being clear that "how you want to solve this problem" the automatically doesn't answer things.

Comment: Is it impossible. Though mathematics or logisticals point of view. Because you have 1 + 1 = B  aka the formula and the calculation is the determination of the formula, how the heck you don't want its intervention?

Comment: Tyþë-Ø thanks for trying tough. I wasn't looking for someone to solve the problem for me, I'm just looking for an idea or some guidance. I have explained the best I could so if you did not understand it still, it's ok. Thank you for your comments anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to my issue.

Everything is based on a calendar for 2021, with every month's days divided by weeks.
The table where I wanted the number of hours for every week to be calculated is linked to that calendar, using HLOOKUP, for every week of a given month.

By referencing the calculations table to the calendar using HLOOKUP and a dropdown list (for every month of the year) I can now change the month and the corresponding weeks are changing accordingly.

I have linked the formulas (based on IFs and SUMIFS) to each week for a given month and this way, the calculations are made automatically whenever I change the month.

Answer (score 0):

There's indeed a way depending in what version or program similar to Excell is.

> Excell is intelligent enough to change values automatically

Your question still not clear, but maybe you want to copy the formula and paste to another cell and maybe to another sheets without having to change every single formula values, but adapting it.

Easy,

- Simply copy with `Ctrl+C` and Paste with `Ctrl+V` or `Ctrl+Alt+V` (but if it's not Mac I believe).

Comment: Hello. I have updated the question. I hope it is clearer now. 
So basically, I need to find a way that, whenever I paste data for another month, the Total Logged Hours column to update the results based on what I paste in the data source sheet.